# C++ использование map[] с простыми типами

Tags: c++, stl, map

Если я напишу так:

```
int main()
{
  map<int, int> my_map;
  my_map[0]++;
}
```

Будет гарантировано, что my_map[0] == 1? Т.е. при вызове my_map[0] создается std::pair< int const ,int>, но зануляеться ли второй аргумент, или там может быть все что угодно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, гарантируется - значения фундаментальных типов инициализируются нулевым инициализатором (надеюсь, с названием не напутал... типа конструктора по умолчанию :)), который дает переменным нулевые значения (для `bool` - `false`).

Comment: Почему именно так? Ведь если я создам переменную какого нибудь базового типа, например int. Там будет лежать мусор.

Comment: Потому что стандарт :) И потому что если вы создадите переменную как `int i;` - это совсем не то же самое, если вы напишете `int i{};` или там `int i = int();`...

Answer (score 0):

Не забывайте, что   `std::map`  содержит элементы с уникальным ключом(каждый ключ единчтвенный)

```
mapped_type&
std::map::operator [](const key_iype& k)
```

выполняет поиск по ключу  `k`, и возвращает соответствующее значение `mapped_type`, **а если ключ `k` не найден, то  в ассоциативный массив вставляется элемент с эти ключом и значением по умолчанию типа  `mapped_type`.**  Т. е. в вашем случаи  `my_map[0]`  возвращает `int()`, значение которого равен нулю, заодно вы просто инкрементировали его и получили единицу